# R: Use formula notation to define a function, like purrr::map(.f=)

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, r-package

In the gtsummary package, there are many functions that take other functions as arguments.  At the moment, the user must pass a proper function, but I would like to update to allow users pass functions with shortcut notation using formula syntax (similar to how `purrr::map()` allows users to pass either `purrr::map(.f = mean)` or `purrr::map(.f = ~mean(.x))`. There are other functions throughout the tidyverse, for example, in dplyr that use similar notation. Here's the description from the `purrr::map()` help file:

[image]

I wrote a small function that converts the formula syntax into a new function. BUT, this only accepts the dot notation (e.g. `~mean(.)`). How can I generalize this to accept `.`, `.x`, and `..1`? In my use case, I need to call them with `foo(1:5)` (not referencing the argument name), and the function will only have a single argument.

```r
# convert a formula to a function
formula_to_function <- function(x) {
  function(.) eval(rlang::f_rhs(x), list(.))
}

# create a new function that is the mean of a vector
foo <- formula_to_function(~mean(., na.rm= TRUE))

# evaluate function
foo(1:5)
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, `purrr::map` uses `purrr::as_mapper` to parse the `.f` argument into a function. See [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/master/R/map.R) (line 110). So one option is to directly use `purrr::as_mapper` in your function, or you can try to rewrite `as_mapper` yourself (here's the [implementation](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/master/R/as_mapper.R)).

Answer (score 1):

`match.funfn` in gsubfn is like `match.fun` in base R except it also accepts a formula.  The formula can use any variables and it is such that any free variables (used but not defined) are assumed to be arguments in the order encountered.

```
library(gsubfn)

f <- function(x, y, z, fun) {
  fun <- match.funfn(fun)
  fun(x, y, z)
}

# test
f(1, 2, 3, ~ a + b + c)
## [1] 6
```

Optionally you can specify the arguments on the LHS of the formula

```
# same
f(1, 2, 3, a + b + c ~ a + b + c)
## [1] 6
```

or pass a function

```
# same
f(1, 2, 3, function(a, b, c) a + b + c)
## [1] 6
```

There are additional features so see the gsubfn package documentation for more info.

Also it is possible to pass formulas as function arguments to general functions by prefacing the function called with `fn$` .

```
library(gsubfn)

f2 <- function(x, y, z, fun) {
  fun(x, y, z)
}

fn$f2(1, 2, 3, ~ a + b + c)
## [1] 6
```